# @babel/preset-react in next.config.js is not loaded with babel-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, next.js, styled-components

My webpack is not transpiling my jsx (and perhaps styled-components) properly so I think that babel is not being run correctly! I'm not sure if it's the styled-components that aren't working or if it's straight react.

I am getting **SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = withImages({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    ...config,
  },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          from: path.join(
            __dirname,
            process.env.ENV !== 'production'
              ? 'favicons/staging/favicon.ico'
              : 'favicons/production/favicon.ico',
          ),
          to: path.join(__dirname, 'public/favicon.ico'),
        },
        {
          from: path.join(
            __dirname,
            process.env.ENV !== 'production'
              ? 'favicons/staging/favicon'
              : 'favicons/production/favicon',
          ),
          to: path.join(__dirname, 'public/favicon/'),
        },
      ]),
    )

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['next/babel', '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            plugins: [
              'babel-plugin-styled-components',
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
              [
                "babel-plugin-root-import",
                {
                  "paths": [
                    {
                      "rootPathPrefix": "~",
                      "rootPathSuffix": ""
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
              ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    })

    return config
  },
})
```

Comment: Instead of manually adding additional Babel rules to the webpack config (by the way, you’re adding both rules to the server and client, in addition to the rules that are already present), instead just create a custom `babel.config.js`. Next will then append this custom config to the Webpack rules during run and build time.

Comment: Take a look at some of the official examples for custom Babel configs, for example: [with-styled-components](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I dont need the answer